# Is this a static method? "static {...}"

Tags: java

I was going through an exercise in Head First Java. It has the following code :

```
static {
System.out.println("Super constructor block");
}
```

i dont get the static modifier that is before the curly braces. What is it called? I know static variables etc. I tried searching online but couldn't get an answer. Thanks.

Comment: this is a static block

Answer (score 5):

It is called a *static initialization block*. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html:

> A *static initialization block* is a normal block of code enclosed in braces, `{` `}`, and preceded by the `static` keyword.

It executes once the class is loaded by the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `static` block not `static` method.

- `static` blocks are different than `static` methods.
- `static` blocks need not be called and are automatically executed. `static` blocks insure that they are only called once, When the class gets loaded.
- `static` blocks can be written anywhere in the class, before execution compiler will combine all `static` blocks and execute at once on class load.
- You can only initialize/access static variables/methods in a `static` block. Which means you cannot access `non-static` variables inside a `static` block, same as with a `static` method.
- As static methods can be called more than once unlike blocks, which makes methods reusable, which is downside of blocks.
- Static blocks are normally used to initialise static variables or do other calculations which are needed before a class instance is created or any static field is accessed..

For more information, refer to these links:

[JavaCode.in](http://www.javacode.in/static-block-in-java/)

[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Comment: Your welcome.. no upvotes :(

Comment: static variables can be accessed outside static blocks..

Comment: check your 4th point

Comment: it just says we can access only static variables in the block... meaning non-static variables cannot be access inside the block!!!

Comment: however i have added further clarification!

Answer (score 1):

This is called "static block". It is executed only once: the first time you make an object of that class or the first time you access a static member of that class (even if you never make an object of that class). [See this link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-79/)